# How to show a polynomial map that is a one-to-one, but not an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I need some help with this one,

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to V=V(y^3-x^4)$ defined by $f(t)=(t^3,t^4)$. Show that altough $f$ is one-to-one, onto polynomial map, $f$ is not an isomorphism.

Comment: Doesn't $V$ have a singularity at the origin?

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you need to show that the corresponding maps of
affine coordinate rings
$$F:\frac{k[x,y]}{(y^3-x^4)}\to k[t]$$
induced by $F(x)=t^3$ and $F(y)=t^4$ is **not** an isomorphism of rings.